# How do you count distinct customers who show no activity after 3 months?

Tags: looker-studio

| ID | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | August 2022 |
| 2 | August 2022 |
| 2 | September 2022 |
| 2 | October 2022 |
| 2 | November 2022 |

The result I'd expect to see is:

|  | Active | Churned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| August 2022 | 2 | 0 |
| September 2022 | 2 | 0 |
| October 2022 | 2 | 0 |
| November 2022 | 1 | 1 |
| December 2022 | 1 | 0 |

I've tried a lot - including blending two tables together and calculating the difference of months from the latest record using `DATETIME_DIFF()`. I just can't seem to get the data to display correctly.

Here's a [link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/482fc827-3a0d-43b9-94f7-62d5d4bb2ac3/page/p_e61qw97m0c/edit) to a Data Studio report with mock data.

Comment: is your backend source google sheets or other?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow - My real one is a database (BigQuery). For demo purposes I've created a spreadsheet to work off of. (Btw, I learned a lot from your last answer - thank you! Just not quite enough yet I guess... ) :)

Comment: as of now I cannot think of a way to achieve this solely by inbuilt studio blends/calculated fields. Hoping someone else would pitch in & offer a way to do it. I would've given a shot if the backend is at least sheets but that's not the case here since you use BQ.

Comment: That's helpful - in that case, if no one responds, I'll take a stab at a big query view to grab the data as a work around. I'd assumed I was missing something within Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

if any one comes along with an inbuilt solution at a later point, that would be awesome but here's the alternative in the mean time to get the expected output.

- columns A, B has the raw data
- cell D2 has the following formula which covers the D, E, F columns

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A$2:A,B$2:B,B$2:B},"Select Col1, min(Col3), max(Col2) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL group by Col1 label max(Col2) '' ,min(Col3) ''"))`

- cell H2 has the following formula which aligns the data in a format thats now compatible to achieve the expected output pivot table. columns H, I would be the backend connections to studio

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT( REGEXREPLACE( MAP(E2:E,F2:F,lambda(gx,hx,if(gx="",,JOIN("|",EDATE(EDATE(gx,-1),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(gx,hx,"m")+4,1)) &""&"ACTIVE")))),"ACTIVE$","CHURNED") ,"|")),"")),"Select * Where Col2!=''"))`

-

[image]